# C# SQLite deleting rows really slow

Tags: c#, sqlite

I created a script to delete just about 180 rows in a local sqlite database. Here is my code:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    sql_con.Open();

    using (var trans = sql_con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        foreach (int i in toDelete)
        {
            cmd = String.Format("DELETE FROM document WHERE docid = '{0}'", i);
            sql_cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmd, sql_con);
            sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        trans.Commit();
    }

    sql_con.Close();
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I tested it with a stopwatch and Debug.WriteLine...it takes randomly about 2-12 seconds. But it should only take about some milliseconds. The docid column is marked as a index column and in the database are not more than 500 rows or so.

If I use the same script to insert things, it takes just about some milliseconds.

Any ideas?

EDIT 1:
This are my PRAGMA's

```
PRAGMA AUTO_VACUUM=0;
PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;
PRAGMA COUNT_CHANGES=OFF;
PRAGMA TEMP_STORE=MEMORY;
```

EDIT 2:
This is my database script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS document (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  docid TEXT NOT NULL,
  key TEXT NOT NULL,
  value TEXT,
  UNIQUE (docid, key)
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS docid_index ON document (docid);
```

EDIT 3:
This is my latest script with all the changes:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    sql_con.Open();
    Debug.WriteLine("After open {0} seconds.", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    stopwatch.Restart();

    using (var trans = sql_con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
        sql_cmd.Transaction = trans;
        sql_cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM document WHERE docid = '@docid';";

        foreach (int i in toDelete)
        {
            sql_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docid", i);
            sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("After execute nonQuery {0} seconds.", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        stopwatch.Restart();
        trans.Commit();
        Debug.WriteLine("After commit {0} seconds.", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        stopwatch.Restart();
    }

    sql_con.Close();
    Debug.WriteLine("After close {0} seconds.", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    stopwatch.Stop();

}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: First thing I'd do would be to stop injecting values directly into the SQL - instead, use parameterized SQL. It may not improve the performance, but basically you should never build SQL for values. Next, I'd try using "in" with a single command, instead of looping.

Comment: After you take Jon Skeet's first advice and use parameterized SQL, an alternative to using `IN (...)` is reuse the `SQLiteCommand` object for different values, which most probably will also improve performance.

Comment: Please specify the transaction object using the Transaction property of the SQLiteCommand: sql_cmd.Transaction = trans; just after you create it.

Comment: Does sqlite not support a 'delete from table where id in' or similar construct?

Comment: Jon Skeet, the data is from my own webservice, so there is no problem to use it like that...
@Larry, I tried adding it but it makes no difference.

Comment: Could you please add a sql_cmd.Dispose(); after the Execute(), just to see.

Comment: @Larry: Makes no difference, it seems that the commit takes the time.

Comment: Well. Is docid defined as a primary key or indexed ?

Comment: It is indexed in the database

Comment: Have you tried to set your connection string using PRAGMA synchronous = 0 ? Have a look just [here](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous). Unfortunately it is less safe than the default option.

Comment: Yes I've set that. I updated my original post with my pragma's.

Comment: Are the TEXT fields containing a large amount of data ? I mean, a XML document, a picture, a file content or something like that ?

Comment: I updated it to Integer. But it makes no differrence. It is a 10 digit long number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The funny thing is, when I tested this whole script in another program, it takes just some milliseconds to delete about 500.000 rows. So there might be a strange bug in the framework...However, I initially deleted the rows after I saved the new ones, if I delete the rows before I save the new ones, it work fine.

So if anyone has a similar problem, try to delete first.

Answer (score 1):

Try to send everything together

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    sql_con.Open();

    using (var trans = sql_con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        foreach (int i in toDelete)
        {
            cmd += String.Format("DELETE FROM document WHERE docid = '{0}';\n", i);             
        }
        sql_cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmd, sql_con);
        sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        trans.Commit();
    }

    sql_con.Close();
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: I tried it and it takes also about 2 to 12 seconds.

Comment: Did you debug what happens on the sql side? Did you execute that? Can you trace times? Are you sure is not the open/close?

Comment: I'm totally sure about that because I call the Debug.WriteLine before the close and I start the stopwatch after the open method, when I try to delete those rows with a sqlite explorer, it takes about some milliseconds.

Comment: Ok, why dont you check that before the open, after the open, before commit tran, and before and after the close.

Comment: Okey, the commit method takes that time.
After open 0.0005234 seconds.
After execute nonQuery 0.0015894 seconds.
After commit 11.6901076 seconds.
After close 1.72E-05 seconds.

Comment: Have you used a profiler to determine where the time is spent?

Comment: It's spend on the commit method.